# How to access info on a flashdrive connected to a router?

Tags: java, server, usb, text-files, router

So I want to write a java program for my family to share anonymous information when playing a board game. The only specifics you need to know are basically I would like to send out a string from a program, wait for a button press, then output the answers to everyone's program.

I have 0 experience with working with servers/connectivity, so I figured the easiest solution could be connecting a USB drive to my router and just writing .txt files to it which I can read from. My only problem is I can't seem to access the USB drive through code, since I can't find a location for it. The only way I can is through Netgear's online router management site. It gives me the following information about it:

- Access Method (Network  Neigboarhood/MacShare, HTTP, HTTPS(via internet), FTP, FTP(via internet))
- Link (various web addresses that I can click and it will take me to pages where I can download items on the USB stick)
- Port (various numbers, some editable)

Using this stuff, is there any way to access the USB drive through a program? I can't seem to find any information about this online, so I hope you guys can help.

Also, if you have any other ideas on how to accomplish what I want to do, pleas let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Check out this website: http://usb4java.org/ and the quickstart: http://usb4java.org/quickstart/libusb.html

Comment: This not (at this point) a programming question, and it is way too broad even if it was.  But when I googled for "usb share router" I saw some promising resources on how to access files on a USB device connected to a router.

Comment: Some routers have the ability to present attached storage (could be drive, could be flash) as a NAS and then all you have to do is open a CIFS network location,